# Is there a more efficient way of chunking a text file whilst maintaining encoding and headers?

Tags: c#

I need to split text files in my application into 256mb chunks, the source files are UTF-16 encoded. The files are tab delimited and have logical headers. Both the encoding and headers must be maintained across chunks.

I've written the following method to do this based on the assumption that 1 utf-16 character occupies 2 bytes.

The code works as intended but is quite slow, I'm wondering if there's any optimizations can be made and if it can be turned into a parallel process?

```
private void ChunkUTF16(FileInfo file, int chunkSize)
        {
            var size = chunkSize * 1024 * 1024 / 2;
            var total = 0;
            var i = 0;
            var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            if (file.Directory != null)
            {
                var filePath = file.Directory.FullName;
                var extension = file.Extension;

                string firstLine = null;
                var dest = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(filePath, $"{fileNameWithoutExtension}_{i}.{extension}"));
                var writer = new StreamWriter(dest.OpenWrite(), Encoding.Unicode);

                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file.FullName))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLine)) firstLine = line;
                    var length = line.Length;

                    if (total + length >= size)
                    {
                        i++;
                        total = 0;
                        writer.Dispose();
                        dest = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(filePath, $"{fileNameWithoutExtension}_{i}.{extension}"));

                        writer = new StreamWriter(dest.OpenWrite(), Encoding.Unicode);
                        writer.WriteLine(firstLine);
                        length += firstLine.Length;
                    }

                    writer.WriteLine(line);

                    total += length;
                    total += Environment.NewLine.Length;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var ex = new FileNotFoundException($"File {file.Name} not found!");
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If it works, it is off topic for SO. Better suited for codereview SE to get input on possible improvements.

Comment: What you describe sounds like paging data and writing the pages to a TSV. Big pages but still pages. This doesn't need complicated code, definitely not something as complicated as the code posted here. Since you deal with *lines*, chunk sizes in bytes are useless and can only corrupt data by forcing you to emit incomplete lines

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos incorrect this isn't paging - I need relatively precise 256mb chunks, number of lines is inconsequential to me. Regarding new lines - already accounting for that.

Comment: You need to calculate the size in *lines*, not bytes. Read the header lines from the file and keep them in an array. After that, just start reading as many lines as you need and write them to a file. When you reach the file's limit just close it.

Comment: How is that more efficient, you'd have to continually poll the filesystem to work out how much data you've actually written? I'm not sure how calculating the size in lines helps either? If I don't know how many lines it takes to fill 256mb, what's the point?

Comment: @dcrdev call it what you will, the code is too complicated with variables having greater scope than they need. Breaking the code in separate methods will clean it up and allow optimization of individual methods. For example, you can use async/await to read/write concurrently. The OS and disk *already* buffer data so you *can* read and write concurrently. Use a large buffer for the reader/writer instead of using the tiny defaults (8KB I think)

Comment: You can have two different threads working as a publisher and subscriber, one reading the file and sending lines to the writer thread. Those could be two separate tasks. You could use the classes in the TPL Dataflow library and use a separate block for the publisher or subscriber.

Comment: Well again without preempting the size in bytes of what you're going to write, how can I achieve chunk sizes of 256mb? After all that is the core requirement here..

Comment: @dcrdev no, the core requirement is to split the file fast. To do that, you need to use concurrent operations, proper buffering, *avoid* garbage collections which means you need to limit allocations and *reuse* buffers.

Comment: BTW, what's the point in having a **text** data chunk of exactly 256 MB?

Comment: @dcrdev in .NET Core 2.1 you can use Pipelines to do all this, including batching etc, with minimum allocations at high speed. Check [Marc Gravell's article series](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos with respect the first sentence "I need to split text files in my application into 256mb chunks" , you see the consumer of these chunks needs them to be 256mb and that consumer is out of the scope of my control.

Comment: @dcrdev So that consumer is going to read broken last lines and misplaced first lines? Exact sizes work only if all lines have a fixed length. It doesn't really matter anyway. None of my comments depend on how you count the chunks.

Comment: @dcrdev The "magic" with pipelines is that you can read real chunks but also inspect them, eg to find line endings, and pass only what you need from reader to writer. You get control of how those chunks are combined into *spans*. The writer could write each span into a separate file, starting a new file one when a new span starts

Comment: @dcrdev spans and chunks are managed, which means once you release a span it's available for reuse. No more garbage collection of a couple million temporary strings generated by reading the source line by line. Allocating and *collecting* all that data could be enough to cause 10x-100x delays

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well no the current method takes that into account and the split only occurs on new lines. Yes the chunks aren't exactly 256mb they very by a couple of kb here and there, but they are all less than 256mb; which is the key. Anyway thanks for the linked article, I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how  much memory you have available. Your code is very inefficient as it is literally reading every single line from and to a hard disk.

If you have loads of memory then load into memory using memorystream and then run it.

If the file is bigger than your memory then one way would be to use Filestreams, then look from the end back to find the new line, then write the new filestream at that point. That way you would literally be copying direct from one location to the next and you would only be limited to the speed of your disks.

Comment: Loading a lot of data in memory is *slower* than copying small buffers. The code has to wait for loading to complete before it can even start writing data out.

Comment: You should know that `File.ReadLines` creates an iterator that internally uses a buffered `StreamReader` which reads the data from the disk. So it is not as inefficient as you might think.